# Jtable Not Displaying Images

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon, tablecellrenderer

I've created an array of images obtained from a url a  and I want to display them in a single column, with a new image in each row. As far as I'm aware the code's doing the right stuff, however in the cells meant to contain each image, it returns the BufferedImage@... for each image.

```
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(crawlUrlp).get();
                    Elements img = thumbnails.select("img");
                    for (Element a : img) {

                    URL url = new URL(a.attr("src"));

                    BufferedImage[] imge = {ImageIO.read(url)};

                    for (int i = 0; i < imge.length; i++) {

                        format.addRow(new BufferedImage[]{imge[i]});

                    }
                }
```

So I then wrote an image cell renderer:

```
public class BufferedImageCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if (value instanceof BufferedImage) {
        setIcon(new ImageIcon((BufferedImage) value));
        setText(null);

        }
    return this;
}
```

}

Which doesn't seem to do much. Am I right in thinking that, despite the output saying 'BufferedImage', I've actually produced a string array? How do I show these images???

Comment: Your renderer looks fine.  How are you installing it in the JTable?

Answer (score 1):

> So I then wrote an image cell renderer:

No need to create a custom renderer.

Instead you should store an image icon in the TableModel:

```
//format.addRow(new BufferedImage[]{imge[i]});
format.addRow(new Object[]{new ImageIcon(imge[i])});
```

Now you need to override the TableModel to tell the table that you are storing Icons in the model so the table can use the proper renderer. Something like:

```
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
   {
    @Override
       public Class getColumnClass(int column)
       {
           return (column == 0) ? Icon.class : super.getColumnClass(column);
       }
   };
```

A simple example showing the concept:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JFrame
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        Icon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
        Icon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
        Icon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {aboutIcon, "About"},
            {addIcon, "Add"},
            {copyIcon, "Copy"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        new TableRowResizer(table);

        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
        tca.adjustColumns();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableIcon frame = new TableIcon();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's indeed column 0 that needs rendering, although, what do i put in place of data and columnNames? I've named all three of my columns ""

Comment: @MaxLewisHawkins, That was an example of how to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method. Read the `DefaultTableModel` API for other constructors you might use. There is one where you specify the column names and 0 rows so you can dynamically add rows to the model

Comment: Sorry to keep asking... So basically, I've already made the JTable using netbeans in my GUI and I don't want to change it/create a new one. How do I override the model for my current jTable, retaining the same format as before I overrode the default model?? something along the lines of jTable1.getModel() ??

Comment: you answered a similar question with: a) override the getColumnClass() method of the JTable or the TableModel to return the class of data in the column. In this case you should return an Icon.class.

Comment: @MaxLewisHawkins, I don't use an IDE. I prefer to learn how to use Java/Swing effectively then to learn how to use an IDE. I have no idea how NetBeans works. Somehow in the IDE you just need to add the basic code I gave you above after the table is created but before you load data into it the first time.

Comment: How do i do this just for the jTable?

Comment: @MaxLewisHawkins, I don't know what your code looks like. Somewhere you need jTable.setModel( model ). I don't know why this is so difficult. Before you must have added a custom renderer to the table, so you could add the code there. Or before you added a row to your table so you could add the row there. I can't give you advice since I don't know the code. Somewhere in your project you must have code where you change the default properties of components. Maybe you change the background or a font or something. All you are doing with the table is changing the model.

Comment: @MaxLewisHawkins, I added a simple example showing the concept. Yes, this example overrides the getColumnClass of the table, but the concept is exactly the same when you override the DefaultTableModel. How you implement it in your code is up to you.